# How to copy a slice to itself

Tags: go, copy, slice

What I mean is, for example

```golang
arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
arr = copy(arr, arr)
fmt.Println(arr) // Expectation: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] Reality: [1, 2, 3]
```

I also tried

```golang
for _, el := range(arr) {
    arr = append(arr, el)
}
```

None of these work.

Comment: While the A.R. Answer is better, your attempt with the append inside a loop should also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arr = append(arr, arr...)`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/AD-r9SP610u):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
    arr = append(arr, arr...)
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 1 2 3]
```